# Centering a Modified List of Figures Title

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, includegraphics, renewcommand, center

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows one to make bold smallcaps.


\newcommand\NewCaption[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{\scshape{#2 #1}}}}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\LARGE\textbf LIST OF ILLUSTRATIONS}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}{%         % Figure label command
  \scshape                          % Small caps
  \bfseries                         % Bold
  \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}  % Dotted line
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-a}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \NewCaption{ImageA Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-b}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \NewCaption{ImageB Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

which produces the List of Figures display:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I modify the command `\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\LARGE\textbf LIST OF ILLUSTRATIONS}` so that the title is centered? I have not been able to accomplish this without error.

Thank you.